# How to show the titles properly in an expandable menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to do a expandable menu in ***jQuery*** and ***CSS3***, here is the fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/mNcuQ/3/**

When you click the slidebar, the titles section is showed. But I'm afraid it doesn't look properly. What I'm trying to do is when the `.expanded` class is active and the width of the slidebar is modified ( with the transition finished ) then show the titles of the menu with fade in effect. As I do now, the titles of the menu are not respeting the `display: inline-block`. Surely I'm missing something...

Do you have any idea or tip to do it? What is better to use in this case: *CSS3 transition* or *jQuery animation*?

Here is the code of the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <a class="btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <nav id="nav" class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li class="active" data-section="1"><i class="icon-home"></i>  <span>Home</span>

            </li>
            <li data-section="2" class=""><i class="icon-rocket"></i>  <span>Services</span>

            </li>
            <li data-section="3" class=""><i class="icon-laptop"></i>  <span>Projects</span>

            </li>
            <li data-section="6" class=""><i class="icon-money"></i>  <span>Price</span>

            </li>
            <li data-section="4" class=""><i class="icon-pencil"></i>  <span>Team</span>

            </li>
            <li data-section="5" class="last"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>  <span>Contact</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#sidebar').click(function () {
        $('html').toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: #151515;
    height: 120%;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#nav {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li i {
    font-size : 15px;
}
#nav ul li {
    color: #F1F1F1;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 22px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    opacity: .4;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 70%;
}
#sidebar {
    -webkit-transition: width 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: width 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: width 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: width 500ms ease;
    transition: width 500ms ease;
}
#nav ul li.active {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
#nav ul li.last {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
#nav li span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 0;
}
.btn-navbar {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 5px 10px;
    opacity: .4;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
.btn-navbar .icon-bar {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
}
/* Expanded Nav Styling */
 .expanded #container {
    left: 100px;
    transform: translate3d(50px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
.expanded #sidebar {
    width: 150px;
}
.expanded #nav li {
    width: 90%;
}
.expanded #nav li span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
}
```

If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use transition-delay maybe?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNcuQ/4/) (moved revelant css classes to bottom)

```
#nav li span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  transition:opacity 0.5s ease; // ease opacity
}

.expanded #nav li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
  width: auto;
  transition-delay: 500ms; //delay transition by the same amount of sidebar width transition time
}
```

Comment: that's perfect! I did know this property. but now... when the animation of width is running the position of the icons changes. Do you have any idea to fix this? Thanks! :)

Comment: it's because of the width and height of the .expandad #nav li spans. just remove auto height and width from second class.
http://jsfiddle.net/mNcuQ/6/

Comment: off-topic side-node: you could also make it js-free, open-on-mouseover side menu with really simple changes (also added hover effect to list items, they fade in) :http://jsfiddle.net/STJHS/1/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you expanded container is too small to position the headlines correct, make it a bit larger and it will work

```
.expanded #sidebar {
  width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, but this is not my problem. Read again the question, please. Thanks.

Comment: well, the title-span's width is depending on the text, and if the width is greater then the bar's width - icon, it can't display inline-block because there's not enough space in the line left

Comment: yeah, I mean when the animation is runing it position changes. I'd like it would stay static, I'm clear? Is little complex to explain, sorry. Thanks.